# Accidentally moved FUSE mounted mount point, not cannot unmount. Any option besides reboot?

Tags: mount, fuse, linux

I mounted a disk image using a few different FUSE modules and then subsequently renamed the parent directory.

The mounts have disappeared from the mtab and now the OS refuses to unmount them.

`fusermount -u mnt` returns:

```
    fusermount: entry for /home/catskul/foo/mnt not found in /etc/mtab
```

`sudo fusermount -u mnt` returns:

```
    fusermount: failed to unmount /home/catskul/foo/mnt: Device or resource busy
```

`sudo fuser -a mnt` returns:

```
    Cannot stat file /proc/986/fd/55: Permission denied
    mnt:
```

Answer (score 1):

Killing the process that had the "permission denied" fd and then subsequently issuing `fusermount -u mnt` did the trick.